# Fetch specific value from output using grep+regex and store in variable in shell

Tags: regex, shell, ubuntu, sh

First seeking apology  for this silly question as i am not expert at all on this.

I have get the out put from a task like below:

```
image4.png PNG 1656x839 1656x839+0+0 8-bit sRGB 155KB 0.040u 0:00.039
image4.png PNG 1656x839 1656x839+0+0 8-bit sRGB 155KB 0.020u 0:00.030
Image: image4.png
Channel distortion: AE
red: 0
green: 0
blue: 0
all: 0 
image4.png=>tux_difference.png PNG 1656x839 1656x839+0+0 8-bit sRGB 
137KB 0.500u 0:00.140
```

From here, i only want to get the value of **all**

For this i am trying to do this:

```
var="$(compare -verbose -metric ae path/actual.png path/dest.png path/tux_difference.png 2>&1 | grep 'all:\s(\d*)')"
```

But it does nothing.

**use**

```
"sudo apt-get install imagemagick"
```

**to make compare workable. recommend to use same Image for source and destination, otherwise you will get error for some image mismatch.**

[image: click here to]

Comment: Use `grep -oP 'all:\s*\K\d+'` or even `grep -oP '^all:\s*\K\d+$'`

Comment: now, execution stop and in console, it shows >   . I have use ctrl+c to stop it

Comment: Try `awk -F": " '{if ($1 == "all") {print $2;}}'`

Comment: No ...still no output ...  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to escape your parenthesis (or just remove them) in:

```
grep 'all:\s\(\d*\)'
```

However grep by default will print the whole line, which is not what you want. Printing only the matched text is possible, but extracting the number from that requires a more complex regex which may or may not be available in your version of grep. GNU grep has the `P` flag to enable Perl like regex, and outputting the match only can be done with the `o` flag.

On the other hand, my recommendation is to use Perl directly:

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /all: (\d+)/'
```

Note that you also don't need those quotes around `$()`. Considering your `compare` call is working properly and outputting the text in your question, then this should do what you asked:

```
var=$( compare [...] | perl -ne 'print $1 if /all: (\d+)/' )
echo $var
```

You can also use variations like `/all:\s*(\d+)/` if the white space before the number is not guaranteed to be there.

---

The Perl code used here is largely based on the `-n` flag, which assumes the following loop around the program:

```
while (<>) {
    # ...
}
```

This loops iterates over the input line by line, and the `<>` already assumes input as either stdin or filenames given as arguments.

The `-e` flag precedes the code itself:

```
print $1 if /all: (\d+)/;
```

Which is just a shorthand for:

```
if (/all: (\d+)/) {
    print $1;
}
```

Here the match operator `m//` (or `/<regex>` for short) tests the default variable `$_` to see if there is a match for the regex. Who had set the `$_` variable? The loop itself in its `(<>)` construct. It automatically sets `$_` to each line being read.

If the regex matches, we print it's first set of parenthesis (group), which has its contents set to `$1`. If the regex had other groups, they would be stored in `$2`, `$3`, and so forth.

Comment: that works exactly  what i want . Thanks ... but what you do by perl seems complex to me, i have to understand it ...... :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you @EricIpsum :) I've just updated the answer with information on how the Perl part works. I tried to keep it simple, without going too much into Perl details. Let me know if it is clear enough!